# What is ||x||^2 in Matlab written as?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I'm trying to write mean shift and I need to compute `||x||^2` as input to the kernel in MATLAB where `x` is an `n x d` matrix, referenced from the article in wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_shift#Code_implementations).

Is it written as `x.^2` or `x'*x`? I tried the first and seems fine with the test but it just doesn't look right. The definition of `||x||^2` is `x.'*x`, but the second one gives wrong results.

Comment: Is `x` a vector?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth `where x is a n nxd matrix` . It was already in the question

Comment: It's in the question now that you've edited it, yes :/

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth it was even before. I just added `nxd`.

Comment: Can I get an answer or we talk more about edits?

Comment: If `x` is real, then `x'*x` is equivalent to *X^T X*.  If `x` is complex, you'd generally want `x.'*x`.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth How does x.'*x  change from x'*x? As I know x' means for each element of x. How can we have transpose of that?

Comment: See https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ctranspose.html vs. https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/transpose.html.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth So to my question ||x||^2 corresponds to which of those operations?

Comment: See my previous comment.

Comment: If `x'*x` is wrong, try `x*x'`. I sometimes find my matrices defined the wrong way around. You definitely need `'`, not `.'`, it's the conjugate transpose that yields the magnitude.

Comment: @CrisLuengo thank you. Now it makes sense. Thanks for that explanation instead of throwing links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If** `||X||^2` is representing a 2-norm, **then** for a

- Vector you can write:

  ```
  sum(abs(X).^2)^(1/2)
  ```
- Matrix you can write:

  ```
  max(svd(X))
  ```

This is how you calculate the 2-norm. However, MATLAB has done that for you with the function `norm`. Using this function as follow calculates the 2-norm

```
norm(X)
```

Comment: Thank you for clarifying it. Apparently yes, it's the 2-norm.